# Good tutorial on how to make custom write panels in Wordpress 3?

Tags: editor

On my last  Wordpress 3 projects I successfully used custom post types and taxonomies coding the implementation by myself. As regards to custom write panels, I always used the [more fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) without any problem.

Now I am developing a whole new theme which needs to be totally independent from that plugin therefore I need to add the custom write panels only by coding.

I did a lot of searching but I was not able to find a good tutorial about it.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always loved [this article](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html) mainly for the reason that its about creating a class to use for your metaboxes.

Comment: Good call, I've come back to that post quite a few times over the last year or so. Definitely a great resource!

Comment: I've extended and custimaized that class, i'll post it when i'll get home.

Comment: It looks like what I was looking for... here is a [snapshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e09892db) of what I mean for "custom write panel"... they are all probably called metaboxes ;)

Comment: @Mirko - yep, in the WordPress language they are called meta boxes.

Answer (score 0):

http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/adding-meta-boxes-to-your-post-screen/
I'm not sure if my writing is good enough, but here is an attempt I made on explaining meta boxes

Are meta boxes what you are looking for?  I'm not crystal on to what exactly you are referring by write panels

Comment: Here is a screeshot [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e09892db), are they all called metaboxes?

Comment: Yup, they are meta boxes.  My link (and a few other posts on my site there) cover it in pretty good detail.  How to add them, how to use the data, etc.